# Probability of euclidean distance between two random points inside a unit circle/sphere greater than 1

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, definite-integrals, conditional-probability, geometric-probability

Problem: Say there are two points inside the circle; `A` and `B`, and they are both randomly drawn according to a uniform distribution where the boundary is the circumference of the unit circle/the surface of the unit sphere. What's the probability that the euclidean distance between two randomly drawn points inside a unit circle/sphere greater than 1?

This question has two versions; the `2D` one and the `3D` one. I have almost gotten down the expression of the integral in `2D` one, but I still get stuck at the late stage of the problem, I haven't tried the `3-D` version just yet, but I guess I will get stuck at a similar stage.

The following is my attempt on the `2-D` version of the problem:

---

Phase 1:

for the sake of simplicity, we can "fix" the angle θ of A to a particular fixed value θa and only vary its r value in the polar coordinate system, so A could be (0,θa), (0.2,θa), (1,θa) etc. 

For B, we can vary everything including radius r and the angle θ of another point `B`.

---

Phase2:

The required probability should be equal to the sum of all of the conditional probability from r=0 to r= 1, where each increment of r is very very small:

ΣP{|A - B| > 1 | A= (r, θa)  }

Upon taking this limiting process to the sum, this becomes a definite integral over the conditional probability density function from r=0 to r=1.

This is where I got stuck, I don't know how to transform the conditional probability to the conditional pdf inside the definite integral and possibly integrate it.

And after this `2-D` version, the `3-D` version is gonna be another beast that I need help in order to deal with that.

---

Note: These are the pictures of my drafts and my guesses, not sure whether they are helpful.

[image: Draft of the 2-D version of the problem]
[image: my guess of what the integral would look like]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This is the solution for the 2D problem**

Fix $A$ to be a distance $r$ from the center of the circle (i.e. fix $|A| = r$). Note that the probability density function of $|A|$ is

$$f_{|A|}(r) = \frac{2\pi r}{\pi} = 2r \qquad r \in [0,1]$$

The $2\pi r$ is the "area" of the circle representing all possible $A$ for which $|A| = r$; and the $\pi$ in the denominator is the total area of the unit circle.

Given that $|A| = r$, what is the probability that $|A-B| <1$?

Draw a circle of radius $1$ centered at $A$, and find the area common to both circles. After a bit of geometry, you should find that the answer is $2\cos^{-1} \frac r2 - \frac{r\sqrt{1-r^2}}{2}$. Thus,

$$\Bbb P(|A-B|<1 \, \big| \, |A| = r) = \frac 1\pi \bigg(2\cos^{-1} \frac r2 - \frac{r\sqrt{1-r^2}}{2}\bigg)$$

Finally, we use the law of total probability:

\begin{align}
\Bbb P(|A-B|<1) & = \int_0^1 \Bbb P(|A-B|<1 \, \big| \, |A| = r) \cdot \color{red}{f_{|A|}(r)} \, dr \\
& = \int_0^1 \frac 1\pi \bigg(2\cos^{-1} \frac r2 - \frac{r\sqrt{1-r^2}}{2}\bigg) \cdot 2r \, dr \\
& = \frac 1\pi \int_0^1 \bigg(4r\cos^{-1} \frac r2 - r^2\sqrt{1-r^2}\bigg) \, dr \\
& = \frac 1\pi \bigg[ 2r^2 \cos^{-1} \frac r2 + 4\sin^{-1} \frac r2 - \frac 18 \sin^{-1} r - r\sqrt{4-r^2} + \frac 18 (r-2r^3)\sqrt{1-r^2} \bigg]^1_0 \\
& = \frac 1\pi \bigg(\frac{61}{48}\pi - \sqrt 3 \bigg) \\
& = \frac{61}{48} - \frac{\sqrt 3}{\pi}
\end{align}

And of course, what we really want is

$$\Bbb P(|A-B|>1) = 1 - \Bbb P(|A-B|<1) = \frac{\sqrt 3}{\pi} - \frac{13}{48} = 0.2805 \dots$$

As pointed out above in red, you are missing a factor of $2r$ in the integrand.

---

**Here's how to do the integration**

\begin{align}
& \int r\cos^{-1} \frac r2 \, dr \\
= & 4\int u\cos^{-1} u \, du && \text{substituted } u = \frac r2 \\
= & 4 \cdot \frac{u^2}{2} \cdot \cos^{-1} u - 4\int \frac{u^2}{2} \cdot \frac{-1}{\sqrt{1-u^2}} \, du && \text{integrated by parts} \\
= & 2u^2 \cos^{-1} u + 2\int u \cdot \frac{u}{\sqrt{1-u^2}} \, du \\
= & 2u^2 \cos^{-1} u + 2 \cdot u \cdot \big(-\sqrt{1-u^2}\big) - 2 \int 1 \cdot \big(-\sqrt{1-u^2}\big) \, du && \text{by parts again} \\
= & 2u^2 \cos^{-1} u - 2u\sqrt{1-u^2} + 2\int \sqrt{1-u^2} \, du \\
= & 2u^2 \cos^{-1} u - 2u\sqrt{1-u^2} + 2\int \sqrt{1-\sin^2 v} \cdot \cos v \, dv && \text{substituted } u = \sin v \\
= & 2u^2 \cos^{-1} u - 2u\sqrt{1-u^2} + 2\int \cos^2 v \, dv \\
= & 2u^2 \cos^{-1} u - 2u\sqrt{1-u^2} + 2 \bigg(\frac v2 - \frac{\sin (v) \cos (v)}{2} \bigg) \\
= & \frac 12 r^2\cos^{-1} \frac r2 - r\sqrt{1-\frac{r^2}{4}} + \sin^{-1} \frac r2 - \frac r2 \sqrt{1-\frac{r^2}{4}}
\end{align}

The other integral can be done by writing

$$\int r^2\sqrt{1-r^2} \, dr = \int r \cdot \Big(r\sqrt{1-r^2}\Big) \, dr$$

and integrating by parts as suggested.

Comment: Really appreciate your help. It seems I haven’t done math related stuff for so long that I forgot to even consider the marginal pdf of r inside the integral.

Answer (score 2):

**This is the solution for the 3D problem**

The previous post (below this one) was already quite lengthy, so I decided to do this in a new post.

We use the same strategy as before, by first fixing $|A|$. By a similar reasoning, we have

$$f_{|A|} (r) = \frac{4\pi r^2}{\frac 43 \pi 1^3} = 3r^2 \qquad r \in [0,1]$$

The next step is a little trickier this time. We must find the volume common to two unit spheres whose radii are distance $r$ apart.

Using coordinate geometry, we might suppose that the two spheres have boundaries

$$\bigg(x-\frac r2 \bigg)^2+y^2 + z^2 = 1 \qquad \text{and} \qquad \bigg(x+\frac r2\bigg)^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1$$

respectively. By considering the regions $x\in [\frac r2-1,0]$ and $x \in [0, 1-\frac r2]$ separately, we see that the required volume is given by the integral

$$\int_{x=\frac r2-1}^{x=0}\int_{y = -\sqrt{1-(x-\frac r2)^2}}^{y = \sqrt{1-(x-\frac r2)^2}}\int_{z = -\sqrt{1-(x-\frac r2)^2-y^2}}^{z = \sqrt{1-(x-\frac r2)^2-y^2}}dzdydx + \int_{x=0}^{x=1-\frac r2}\int_{y = -\sqrt{1-(x+\frac r2)^2}}^{y = \sqrt{1-(x+\frac r2)^2}}\int_{z = -\sqrt{1-(x+\frac r2)^2-y^2}}^{z = \sqrt{1-(x+\frac r2)^2-y^2}}dzdydx$$

This is a mess. But of course, we can simplify this a little bit by observing the symmetry. So

\begin{align}
\cdots & = 8 \int_{x=0}^{x=1-\frac r2}\int_{y = 0}^{y = \sqrt{1-(x+\frac r2)^2}}\int_{z = 0}^{z = \sqrt{1-(x+\frac r2)^2-y^2}}dzdydx \\
& = 8 \int_{x=0}^{x=1-\frac r2}\int_{y = 0}^{y = \sqrt{1-(x+\frac r2)^2}} \sqrt{1-\bigg(x+\frac r2 \bigg)^2-y^2} \, dydx \\
& = 2\pi \int_{x=0}^{x=1-\frac r2} \bigg(1-\bigg(x+\frac r2 \bigg)^2\bigg) \, dx \\
& = \bigg(\frac 43 - r + \frac{1}{12}r^3 \bigg)\pi
\end{align}

This seems a bit unreasonable, since the 2D problem had $\cos^{-1}$'s and whatnot, yet the 3D problem has such a neat result. However, I have checked with Wolfy, and this seems to be correct.

As before, we then have

$$\Bbb P(|A-B|<1 \, \big | \, |A|=r) = \frac{\bigg(\frac 43 - r + \frac{1}{12}r^3 \bigg)\pi}{\frac 43 \pi} = 1 - \frac 34 r + \frac{1}{16}r^3$$

Finally,

$$\Bbb P(|A-B|<1) = \int_0^1 \bigg(1 - \frac 34 r + \frac{1}{16}r^3\bigg) \cdot 3r^2 \, dr = \frac{15}{32}$$

And

$$\Bbb P(|A-B|>1) = \frac{17}{32}$$

I highly suspect that I have done something wrong, but this is the way to go about this question.

Comment: I think in the 3D version, rather than considering the common area of two spheres to represent the probability, the common volume of two spheres will make more sense.

Comment: It was a typo, but yes that's what I meant.

Comment: If the triple integral done in cartesian coordinate appraoch is correct, then the spherical coordinate approach should yield the same answer. Maybe we can try it later to see if they are consistent.

Comment: I used polar coordinate to calculate the common volume and I also reached the same answer(3/4 - r +r^3/12)*pi. Actually, arccos(r/2) shows up in this approach if rig substitution is used to integrate one part of the integral.